# Get the most recently viewed product variations (commerce product entity) in a View

Tags: 7, views, commerce, entities, nodes

#### Pre-requisite knowledge:

I have a view of type *Content* which is meant to list the most recently viewed product variations (commerce product entities that the product node references) first. I am using the **sort order criteria** - *Content statistics: Most recent view (desc)*.

I understand that this view should ideally have been of type *Commerce Product* and sort order criteria as *Entity statistics: Most recent view (desc)* (provided by [Entity Statistics](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_statistics) module).

#### Problem:

But the real problem is that only the product node page is viewed by the user, not the commerce product page. So the Statistics module (which comes with Drupal 7 core) logs the node view but Entity Statistics does not log the commerce product entity view. So even on using *Entity Statistics - Most recent view (desc)* sort criteria, the most recently viewed product variation doesn't appear first in view results.

Should I build a **custom sort criteria** for this purpose? If so, need help in how to do so and in which **hook** exactly.

Any workarounds or other suggestions are welcome as well!